# Implicit targets not triggered

Tags: makefile

My Makefile is hitting the `static` target when invoked without any parameters, but is then failing because its dependencies are not being built. I've set the dependencies up as implicit rules and if I invoke them manually, `make` says that there's nothing for it to do (even though there is)... I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I cannot see what:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -fpic -O3

all: static shared doc

clean:
    rm -rf *.o


objects=dynamicArray.o directedGraph.o linkedList.o stack.o

dynamicArray.o: indexed/dynamicArray.c indexed/dynamicArray.h
directedGraph.o: graph/directedGraph.c graph/directedGraph.h indexed/dynamicArray.h
linkedList.o: graph/linkedList.c graph/directedGraph.h graph/linkedList.h 
stack.o: graph/stack.c graph/linkedList.h graph/stack.h 


# Static library
static: $(objects)
    $(AR) rcs libCS101.a $(objects)

# Shared library
shared: $(objects)
    $(CC) -shared -o libCS101.so $(objects)

# Documentation
doc: Doxyfile $(find . -name "*.dox" -or -name "*.h")
    doxygen
```

(The `doc` target doesn't work, either. It doesn't pick up changes in the files that `find` should list, which leads me to believe that escaping like this isn't correct...)

Comment: Without checking in depth, I think the problem with your `doc` target is that it should be `$(shell find . -name ...)`

Comment: Also, as a matter of good practice, the instances of `$(objects)` in your recipes should be replaced with `$^` (an automatic variable meaning "all the dependencies"), so that the objects could be compiled to a different directory without breaking the command.

Comment: In the same vein, your `static` and `shared` targets would be better off structured a bit differently. You should have `static: libCS101.a` and `shared: libCS101.so`, and then modify the existing rules to build each of those targets by name. You can then replace the names following `-o` with `$@`, so they too could be built in different places, with Make handling the difference automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Novelocrat :) That fixed everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies for the various object files aren't of the form that Make's built-in compilation rules recognize. It wants a direct mapping of `%.o: %.c`.

Add a VPATH for the `indexed` and `graph` directories, and then take those path components off the `.c` file names.

Comment: What happens if you have `indexed/foo.c` and `graph/foo.c`: which one does it pick?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I would simply say "don't do that" - i.e., name your source files within a single build system realm uniquely.

Comment: Make uses the first one it finds: when you define VPATH to be `indexed graph` it will pick `indexed/foo.c` and when you define VPATH to be `graph indexed` it will pick `graph/foo.c`.